# Prove that if $f'(x) > g'(x)$, $f(a) \ge g(a)$ then $f(x) > g(x)$ in $(a,b]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

There's a similar question here: [If $f(a) = g(a)$ and $f'(x) < g'(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, then $f(b) < g(b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554939/if-fa-ga-and-fx-gx-for-all-x-in-a-b-then-fb-gb) however in the original answer the conditions are a bit different as well as the solution uses Mean value theorem which we didn't learn.

> $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$. $\quad f(a) \ge g(a)$ and $f'(x) > g'(x)$ in $(a,b)$. Prove that $f(x) > g(x)$ in $(a, b]$.

Let $E(x) = f(x) - g(x)$.

If $E(a) = E(b)$ then by Rolle theorem there must be a $c$ such that $E'(c) = 0$.

But $E'(x) = f'(x) - g'(x) > 0$ for $a<x<b$ therefore $E'(x) \neq 0$. Therefore $E(a) \neq E(b)$.

Because $E(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ there must be an absolute minimum and maximum for $E(x)$ in $[a,b]$. According to max/min theorem possible max/min can be on the edges of an interval, where the derivative is $0$ or where derivative doesn't exist. Because $E(x)>0$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ the max/min has to be on the edges.

$E'(x) > 0 \Rightarrow$ $E(x)$ is ascending for $a<x<b$ therefore $E(a)$ = min, $E(b)$ = max.

Because $f(a) \ge g(a)$ then $E(a) \ge 0$. Because $E(a)$ is the absolute min from there $E(b) >E(x)>E(a)$ for $a<x<b$. Of course there can't be any $x_1, x_2$ such that $E(x_1)=E(x_2)$ because then again by Rolle $E'(x)$
 will have a zero but this contradicts the given conditions.

Therefore if $E(b) >E(x)>E(a)$ for $a<x<b$ then $f(x)>g(x)$ for $a<x<b$. Q.E.D.

Please let me know if there were parts I could've skipped in the proof.

Comment: I dont like very much the statement "$E'(x)>0\implies E(x)$ is ascending", this is not totally formal, and proving this result is more complicate that the question on the title, and more complex than the MVT.

Comment: in our class we had a theorem that if $f$ is continuous in [a,b] and $f$ is differentiable in (a,b) and if  $f'(x)>0$ then the function is ascending in [a,b].

Comment: Ok, then your proof is correct. But generally the theorem you says is proved using the MVT.

Comment: In the top of the question I said that we didn't learn MVT therefore I can't rely on it.

Comment: On a side note it looks like MVT is almost identical to the definition of slope and a result derivative. Could I use it if I prove the problem by calculating the slope?

Comment: I dont understand your question. The MVT is a generalization of the Rolle's theorem. I dont know exactly the context where this proof comes from so I cant say something more. As I said if you know the theorem about "$f'(x)>0\implies f(x)$ is increasing" then your proof is ok.

Comment: Can you please confirm that @user251257 answer is correct? It's currently above my understanding and I don't want to blindly accept an answer.

Comment: @Yos you should write `@username` in front of your comment, other wise the user won't be notified. If you have questions about my answer, you could also ask me more questions. I have just outlined the proof that $E$ is strictly increasing, which you have omitted. (I haven't read the comments before I answered.) As for your proof, it looks okay to me, but rather unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $E$ is strictly increasing, is usually proven by MVT. Actually you don't need MVT.

Notice that for $x\in (a,b)$ we have
$$ 0 < E'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \underbrace{\frac1h}_{>0} (E(x+h) - E(x)). $$
That is, there exists some $h_x > 0$ such that for every $h\in (0,h_x)$ it follows $E(x+h) > E(x)$. Now let $y\in (x, b]$. If $E(y) > E(x)$ there is nothing to show. If $E(y) \le E(x)$ you obtain a contradiction by Rolle's theorem.

Then, by continuity of $E$ and for $t\in (0,1)$, $t\to 0$ we have
$$ E(y) > E(x) > E(a (1-t) + xt) \to E(a) \ge 0. $$

Comment: Would somebody explain why he/she down voted?

Comment: It maybe a really great proof but a) you introduce $x$. can't we just write $a$ instead of $x$? From my understanding of your proof they have the same roles. b) you introduce $t$ and you give it a range where you lost me :) Proving that $E$ is ascending is really not my issue, my issue is mainly the part I wrote about min and max which seems to me a bit redundant because once I say $E(a) \ge 0$ and from there it only keeps ascending it seems enough. What do you think?

Comment: @Yos (a) you can't select $x$ as $a$ because $E$ is not necessarily differentiable at $a$. (b) for $a<x$ and $t\in (0,1)$ you have $a < a(1-t) + xt < x$. I need this because I have only shown that $E$ is increasing on $(a,b]$, not on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Do you mean that also you need to show that it's increasing on $[a,b]$? Because from given conditions $E$ doesn't necessarily increase ($E'(a)$ can be $0$).

Comment: @Yos $E$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$. That is part of my proof. Notice $E' > 0$ implies $E$ is strictly increasing. The reversed implication is in general wrong.

Comment: but it is given that $f'>g'$ only on $(a,b)$. If $f(a) = g(a) \Rightarrow E'(x) = 0$ so how can it be increasing?

Comment: @Yos I don't get your question. $E$ need not be differentiable at $a$. If it does, the derivative may be $0$. Consider for example $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = 0$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I'm confused by why you need to prove that $E(x)$ is ascending in $[a,b]$, why $(a,b]$ is not enough especially because we only need to prove that $f(x) > g(x)$ on $(a,b]$

Comment: @Yos only $E(a) \ge 0$ was given. If $E$ is only increasing on $(a,b]$ (and not continuous), it may be negative. But since $E$ is continuous it is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$ and positive on $(a,b]$.

Answer (score -1):

Everything is good except for one thing I believe, you said $f(x) > g(x) \in (a, b]$. Why is it one open one closed?

Comment: Because, from the given information, we can't conclude that $f(a) > g(a)$. They could be equal.

Comment: Sorry I read that part wrong.

Comment: Your proof is correct

Comment: Did I really have to prove that $E(a)$ is min and $E(b)$ is max?

Comment: Thats really a 'seperate' proof. I wouldn't think so